# How to create view with $graphLookup in MongoDB 3.4.0?

Tags: mongodb, view, aggregation-framework

I am creating a view using `$graphLookup` in pipeline but failed. Anyone have any ideas?

`$cmd`:

```
{
  "create": "employee.view.list",
  "viewOn": "employee",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$graphLookup": {
        "from": "employee.view.list",
        "connectToField": "_id",
        "startWith": "$supervisor",
        "connectFromField": "supervisor",
        "as": "supervisors",
        "maxDepth": 10
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error

> View cycle detected: test_sw-aggregation-test.employee.view.list => test_sw-aggregation-test.employee.view.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are creating the view with the same name as the collection on whose documents to perform `$graphLookup`.

Also `employee.view.list` is not a predefined view in which case you would have got an error message that looks like this:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "a view 'employee.view.list' already exists",
    "code" : 48,
    "codeName" : "NamespaceExists"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The view been created by changing 
"from": "employee.view.list" ==> "from": "employee"